# First user removed?

Tags: discussion, support

I just had 20 rep points removed due to the deletion of a user account. **Was this our first removal?** Can we learn whether it was because the user asked it or due to violations of policy? I think this bit of information does not hurt the usual confidentiality surrounding the removal of user accounts.

Comment: Mod checking in. Did not remove.

Comment: @JasonNichols I lost 40 points, reason "User deleted".

Comment: Ah, you're saying *you* did not remove. I misunderstood as *there was no one removed*